# Local variable not available after the declaration batch

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is my very first T-SQL question, so I hope I'm not using the wrong terminology. I just learned some basic stored procedures and variable declaration, however there is something I haven't understood.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()
select @CurrentDate

-----------------------
2013-09-25 18:47:07.547

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If I running the above in two batches ( `declare` and `set` together, `select` after) I get:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()

Command(s) completed successfully.

select @CurrentDate

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentDate".
```

It must probably be simple but I couldn't find a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run these in separate batches, sorry. Variables are scoped to the batch. You shouldn't have to worry about this inside a stored procedure, since you can't add `GO` or execute two portions of the code independently, like you can in Management Studio.

Comment: Variables are scoped to the batch. Clear! Thanks. On my way to learn... :-)