# Using a variable in a temp table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, temp-tables

I am creating a temp table. This is attached to a larger query however i cannot show it so this is a demo. I am putting this into a temp table so the calculated date will be better for the optimiser in a temp table  -

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate = getdate()

CREATE TABLE #Test
(      
             [Date] datetime,
             [Id] uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT INTO #Test 
SELECT                     MAX(l.[Date]) AS [Date],
                       l.[Id] AS [Id]
              FROM     [Table1] AS [l] 
              WHERE l.[Date] <= @CurrentDate
              GROUP BY l.[Id]

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

However, i get the error, **'Must declare the scalar variable "@CurrentDate".'**
Whats the best way to get this working? Is the only way to declare the variable inside the insert select statement? Thanks

Something like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate = getdate()

CREATE TABLE #Test
(      
             [Date] datetime,
             [Id] uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT INTO #Test 
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate = getdate()
SELECT                     MAX(l.[Date]) AS [Date],
                       l.[Id] AS [Id]
              FROM     [Table1] AS [l] 
              WHERE l.[Date] <= @CurrentDate
              GROUP BY l.[Id]

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Comment: The first query has no error better to provide actual query.

Comment: That code doesn't raise that error. It's fine to cut your code down to a minimal size - so long as it still *demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: Also, what makes you think you have to help the optimizer in this way? Generally, it's best to give the optimizer the biggest query you can and let *it* work out how best to compute the result, any intermediate caching, etc.

Comment: ah ok! Well at least i know it should'nt error. I might be able to work it out. thanks

Comment: [Your anwer is already given, check this if it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19012160/4050601)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in batches, you must declare the variable in the same batch as it is used

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(      
             [Date] datetime,
             [Id] uniqueidentifier
);

-- You must run this all in one go
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime
SET @CurrentDate = getdate()
INSERT INTO #Test 
SELECT                     MAX(l.[Date]) AS [Date],
                       l.[Id] AS [Id]
              FROM     [Table1] AS [l] 
              WHERE l.[Date] <= @CurrentDate
              GROUP BY l.[Id]

SELECT * FROM #Test
```